# Python Store Variables

Tags: python, variables, store

I would like to store integers as Rate, Remaining, Battery and kWh. Please help revise this so I can store the variables and perform the equation at the bottom of the code.

```
Rate = 0
while (Rate < 0.5) or (Rate > 2.0):
    Rate = int(raw_input("Enter Desired Rate of Charge: ")) #User will be prompted to enter the charge rate of the system
    if Rate < 0.5:
    #If the charge rate entered is less than 0.5 kWhs
        print "Charge Rate Too Low: Please consider revision" #Tells the user the rate is too low
    elif Rate > 2.0:
    #Also, if the charge rate entered is greater than 2.0 kWhs...
        print "Charge Rate Too High: Please consider revision" #Tells the user the rate is too high
    else:
    #Otherwise, for any number entered between the bounds of 0.5 and 2.0 kWhs...
        print '\n' #Page break for new conditions.

import random
Remaining = random.randint(0, 80) #Simulates remaining charge left over from the last use of the car. Defines the variable as "Remaining"

Battery = 0
while (Battery <=0) or (Battery >=80):
    Battery = int(raw_input("Enter Current Battery Life: "))
    #User will be prompted to enter the current battery level of the car. Defines that variable as "Battery"
    if Battery < 0:
    #If user input level is less than 0 kWh...
        print "Insufficient Entry (Too Low): Please consider revision" # Tells the user that the battery level entered is too low
    elif Battery > 80:
    #Also, if the user input level is greater than 80 kWh...
        print "Insufficient Entry (Too High): Please consider revision" # Tells the user that the battery level entered is too high
    kWh = 80 - Battery - Remaining
    print '\n' #Page break
    if kWh <=0:
        print "Battery Fully Charged!"
        print "There were " Remaining, " kWhs remaing from the last charge. 0 kWhs were charged."
        print "Buckle up! The rewards of the journey far outweigh the risk of leaving the garage!"
    else:
        print "Battery Fully Charged!"
        print "There were " Remaining, " kWhs remaing from the last charge. " kWh, "kWhs were added to recharge battery."
        print "Buckle up! The rewards of the journey far outweigh the risk of leaving the garage!"
```

Comment: This is mostly unrelated to your question, but just a general comment: You don't need to write comments that are completely redundant for somebody who's reading the code. Only comment to explain things that are not obvious. For instance, you don't need to say "if user level is less than 0" just after doing a `< 0` check, since they mean exactly the same thing. Instead, you might want to say *why* zero is a boundary that should be tested. For things like `print` statements there's seldom a need for a comment, since the text being printed is its own documentation.

Comment: A charge rate is not expressed in kWh. kWh is the amount of energy stored. A rate is an amount divided by time, so what you get is (k)W as a rate. BTW, where is the `Rate` used?

Comment: Another thing: According to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should write your variable names in lower case: `battery`, `rate`, `remaining`. And consider renaming `kWh` to `added` or something alike: nearly all values are in kWh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you told us what the problem was (full traceback error), we could have helped you immediately and tell you that

```
print "There were " Remaining, " kWhs remaing from the last charge. 0 kWhs were charged."
print "There were " Remaining, " kWhs remaing from the last charge. " kWh, "kWhs were added to recharge battery."
```

are the problem: you are missing a `,` before `Remaining` and before `kWh`.

Use

```
print "There were", Remaining, "kWhs remaing from the last charge. 0 kWhs were charged."
print "There were", Remaining, "kWhs remaing from the last charge. ", kWh, "kWhs were added to recharge battery."
```

and all gets fine.

If you get similiar errors, look what happens there and correct it until it runs.

BTW: You duplicate code. Better do

```
print "Battery Fully Charged!"
print "There were", Remaining, "kWhs remaing from the last charge. ", # notice the ,
if kWh <=0:
    print "0 kWhs were charged."
else:
    print "kWh, "kWhs were added to recharge battery."
print "Buckle up! The rewards of the journey far outweigh the risk of leaving the garage!"
```

(and I am not sure if it would be better to just write `kWh` instead of `kWhs`. Do unit abbreviations have a plural form? I don't think so...)

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
else:
    while Battery >=80:
        kWh=80-'Battery'-'Remaining'
        print kWh, "kWh"
```

with just plain

```
kWh = 80 - Battery - Remaining
print(kWh, "kWh")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One more thing, how do I later recall the variable "Remaining"?

Comment: It is already stored in the variable binding `Remaining`. Just reference `Remaining` wherever you want to refer to it. Or am I misunderstanding what you're really asking?

Comment: I edited the question. It keeps telling me there is a syntax error.

Comment: should be something like `print "string" + str(variable) + "more string"`. You have to do something to turn your variable into a string (the `str()` function does this) and you have to concatenate the string fragments together (the `+` does that part)